# Show what has inputted after BACK button pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I have two fragments.

`FirstFragment` shows a input form

```
Class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
   ...
}
```

After user submit the form in above `FirstFragment`, the `SecondFragment` is shown.

```
Class SecondFragment extends Fragment{
 ...
}
```

Now, when user press the physical **BACK** button, the `FirstFragment` form is showing again.

At this point, I would like to also show what user has inputted previously, and fill the inputs in the form so that user do not need to input everything again.

How to implement this feature in my two Fragments?

Comment: How about saving the inputs in SharedPreferences?

Comment: I am seeking a way which do not need to use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return to a fragment from the back stack it does not re-create the fragment but re-uses the same instance and starts with onCreateView() in the fragment lifecycle, see Fragment lifecycle.

So if you want to store state you should use instance variables and not rely on onSaveInstanceState().

Answer (score 0):

Override  onSaveInstanceState(), making sure to call super.onSaveInstanceState() to retain the fragment. Restore the state in onCreate(), onCreateView(), or onActivityCreated(). See [Handling the Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) and [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState).

Comment: When I change to 2nd fragment, my onSaveInstanceState() is not called.